# Selecting multiple columns from a data frame using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame with column names

** RI   Na  Mg  Al  Si  K   Ca  Ba  Fe  Type **

Type column is categorical and consists of 4 types. How to extract only RI, Al, Si, Ba columns whose type is 2 using dictionary?

I have tried using the below code:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=df[df['Type']==2], orient='index',columns=['RI','Al','Si','Ba'])
```

I am getting an error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

How do I select only specific columns of type 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First filter the rows of the data frame where type equal to 2 by filtered_df=df[df[Type ==2]] ... Now convert the filtered df to dict using to_dict()
dict = filtered_df.to_dict()
Now from dict u can filter the multiple columns by passings your required columns as key 
keys = ['Ri', 'Ai', 'Si','Ba']
for key in keys:
    dict.get(key)